# ASP.NET MVC 4 Roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-roles

what is the best way to manage roles in MVC 4? I found this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

but I want to be flexible and add the back office user the power to create and assing roles to registred user.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the framework provides an out of the box solution for managing users and roles. It should however be quite easy to roll your own, especially if you use the new SimpleMembership provider.

You can also take a look at the [SecurityGuard](https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard) project, which seems quite nice, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to work with the SimpleMembershipProvider, if it isn't enough, I'll try the SecurityGuard (that seems quite good to me also).

Answer (score 4):

The ASP.NET Configuration site mentioned in that tutorial does not even work with `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

You will need a few custom pages to do the following:

- List users
- Create/Edit user where you display a list of roles.

Then you can just use the built-in functions such as:

```
Roles.RoleExists(role)
Roles.CreateRole(role);
Roles.IsUserInRole(username, role)
Roles.AddUserToRole(username, role);
```

This assumes you are using a built-in provider and the data tables generated by ASP.NET. You can also inherit from the `RoleProvider` class and implement your own methods.